# Custom Authorization Message Handler with custom AuthenticationStateProvider failed on IHttpClientFactory creation

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I use .NET 8 preview and VS2022.

I need a handler for attaching jwt tokens, so I wrote it like this:

```
public class CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler : AuthorizationMessageHandler
{
    public CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler(IAccessTokenProvider provider, IConfiguration configuration, NavigationManager navigation)
        : base(provider, navigation)
    {
        var backendUrl = configuration.GetSection("BackendUrl").Value;
        ConfigureHandler(
            authorizedUrls: new[] {backendUrl});
    }
}
```

and a custom AuthenticationStateProvider

```
public class AuthStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
{
   ...
}
```

everything is configured like this:

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, AuthStateProvider>();
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("myapi", client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(backendUrl!);

}).AddHttpMessageHandler(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler>());

builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient("myapi"));
builder.Services.TryAddScoped(sp => (IAccessTokenProvider) sp.GetRequiredService<AuthenticationStateProvider>());
```

The problem is that I get error

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
> Unhandled exception rendering component: ValueFactory attempted to access the Value property of this instance.
> System.InvalidOperationException: ValueFactory attempted to access the
> Value property of this instance.    at
> System.Lazy`1[[Microsoft.Extensions.Http.ActiveHandlerTrackingEntry, Microsoft.Extensions.Http, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]].ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)    at System.Lazy`1[[Microsoft.Extensions.Http.ActiveHandlerTrackingEntry,
> Microsoft.Extensions.Http, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]].ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper
> executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)    at
> System.Lazy`1[[Microsoft.Extensions.Http.ActiveHandlerTrackingEntry, Microsoft.Extensions.Http, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]].CreateValue()    at System.Lazy`1[[Microsoft.Extensions.Http.ActiveHandlerTrackingEntry,
> Microsoft.Extensions.Http, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]].get_Value()    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.Http.DefaultHttpClientFactory.CreateHandler(String
> name)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.Http.DefaultHttpClientFactory.CreateClient(String
> name)    at Program.<>c.<$>b__0_2(IServiceProvider sp) in
> D:\projects\myapi\Program.cs:line 28

when it tries to instantiate IHttpClientFactory (line 28 is
*builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService().CreateClient("myapi"));*)